# ArgoCD What should I put in the Repository URL and Path fields?

Tags: argocd

I'm using the ArgoCD UI (webapp) and trying to create a new ArgoCD app.
Two of the fields I need to enter are:

- Repository URL
- Path

**In ArgoCD, What value should I put in the Repository URL and Path fields?  Where is the argo documentation at for these fields?**

I did a search and found https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ which may have it.  I'm studying the docs now, but figured other devs might want to know this answer (or I might in another 6 months) so I'm asking here so I can later refer to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Repository URL:** the URL of a Git repository that contains manifests/Kustomize/helm files. Also called a "GitOps" repository.

**Path:** the path within the repository for where to look for files, only the files of this path will be included in the Application.

Multiple ArgoCD apps can target the same repo and different paths (for instance, one folder per component, or per environment, or both..).

Comment: So for the path, is the name a relative path?  So of my code is `myapp/deploy/helm` and that directory contains the *helm chart* (so it has a `Chart.yaml`, `values.yaml` and `templates` directory), then the value in Path would be `deploy/helm`  (where myapp is not included because that is the top of `git clone .../myapp.git` source).